# Android Beginner: Layout Button and Text

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I am trying to create an app where there is a row of buttons and then text directly under the center of the buttons. So far, this is what I have:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/blue"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/red" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/green" android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2.5dip"                       
        android:layout_marginLeft="7.5dip"
        android:text="@string/button1"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2.5dip"
        android:text="@string/button2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_marginTop="2.5dip"           
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:text="@string/button3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

but the text does not line up under the center of the buttons. Can someone please help?

Comment: is FrameLayout your root element? If this is so, it doesnt make sense to have another element beneath alongside the root element (your RelativeLayout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drew, you should be able to center  align them with 2 properties: Gravity and Layout Gravity.
Using just one gravity center property does not work everytime, but by using these two, it should work like a charm for you just like it did for me.

```
android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's never nice to use several childs within a FrameLayout. You should use LinearLayout if you can. If you want the buttons to fill like a third of the width of the screen, you can use

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:weightsum="3" >

     <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/blue"
       android:weight="1"/>

     <Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/red"
       android:weight="1"/>

     <Button
       android:id="@+id/button3"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/green"
       android:weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then for the TextViews, you can again use a LinearLayout, but change the orientation;

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dip"                       
    android:layout_marginLeft="7.5dip"
    android:text="@string/button1"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dip"
    android:text="@string/button2"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dip"           
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:text="@string/button3"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I'm not wrong, this would probably solve your problem.

Comment: This would work, except that I'm using custom buttons and I thus can't use the wieght attribute

Comment: Alright, but do the buttons in your current code work? If they do, just ignore my part about that. Does it work with the TextViews though? Seeing as that was your main problem.

Comment: My current setup works... its just that I'm a little OCD about order. I want the center of the text to be inline with the center of the button. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse you can go to the graphical view of the layout .xml, right-click the view you want centered, go to Layout Vertical or Horizontal and click Gravity -> Center.